# PyQT database (postgresql) connection not working

Tags: postgresql, pyqt

I'm having problem when connecting to my postgresql database. I've used the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtSql import *


db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QPSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("db_hospital")
db.setUserName("username")
db.setPassword("password")
db.setPort(5432)
ok = db.open()

if ok:
    print("Connected to database")
else:
    print("Error connecting to database")
```

Could the problem be that pyqt is installed on C:\, whereas postgresql is installed on E:\?

EDIT: Forgot the error

an instance of qcoreapplication is required for loading driver plugins

EDIT 2: after adding this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
```

I just get the message: Error connecting to database.

EDIT 3: I reinstalled PostgreSQL on my C:\ drive and made it read data from it's old location (E:), but the problem still remains.

Comment: Does postgresql service is running ??

Comment: It wasn't, but I tried running it now and it's still the same.

Comment: Why use QtSQL via PyQT? That seems an incredibly roundabout thing to do. Is it to use Qt widgets that support QtSQL? If not, use `psycopg2` instead.

Comment: I was assigned a task to make database GUI via PyQt. If that's what you're asking :)